# Generate a shared link for a Sharepoint List

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been trying to share access (read/edit) to a Sharepoint list using the API, but I can't seem to find a way to do it specifically for a list.

Somehow the API does not treat lists are files and you can't call them to provide permissions.

I've tried this for both a OneDrive list and Sharepoint Site list.
Is this something which is simply not supported?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you are trying to provide read and write access for the shared folder .

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0#sharing-links) The most common type of permissions are sharing links. Sharing links provide a unique URL that includes both the resource being shared and an authentication token that provides access to the resource. Users don't need to sign-in to access the content shared with a sharing link. An [edit link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0#edit-link) provides read and write access to an item.

POST /shares/{encoded-sharing-url}/permission/grant

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "roles": ["write"],
  "link": {
    "type": "edit",
    "webUrl": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D33DD65C6932946!70859&authkey=!AL7N1QAfSWcjNU8&ithint=folder%2cgif",
    "application": { "id": "1234", "displayName": "Sample Application" }
  },
  "shareId": "!LKj1lkdlals90j1nlkascl",
  "expirationDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Hope this helps

Thanks